# Editing/deleting rows from a UI standpoint?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am just wondering what the best practice might be in regards to allowing a user to edit/delete rows from an app I am creating.

Originally, I had a pencil icon in the action bar, and when it was clicked, it would show a pencil and X icon for each row, allowing the user to edit or delete the row that way.

This was years ago and there may be a better practice now, and I was looking for some feedback on this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tightly depends on what is intention of your app and how flow of actions is designed.

In case of apps where data is represented in rows, you usually use/see CAB enabled with long press with common actions like delete/share/... (like Gmail app). User can for e.g. delete one or multiple rows at once. Edit is usually not such action and you need to use it in other place to avoid possible confusion (otherwise might be unclear for user what actually will be edited). If normal click is not reserved for any special action, then usually when user tap on the row we should show item details. Once we are showing details, we can show actions in Action Bar that are specific only for that item and also common actions, like edit/delete/... (see native Contacts app).

Good articles on this topic are [Patterns-App Structure](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html) and [Patterns-Selection](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html).